# Finding the Second Derivative of an integral within an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Looking at the following equations, I think that g'' is some form of the equation within f(x). However, it's a bit too much to wrap my head around and I am not exactly sure how to get there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You will use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus twice, which states that $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)dt=f(x).$$

So to get you started, can you say what $g(y)$? Notice:

$$g'(y)=\frac{d}{dy}g(y)=\frac{d}{dy}\int_3^yf(x)dx$$

Comment: thank you! If you wouldn't mind me taking some more of your time, does [this](https://i.imgur.com/HAMlAJT.png) look like the correct formula for g''(y)?